# How to copy all schema from one database to other database (created at runtime)?

Tags: sql-server

I have used schema for tables for one database,so how to copy all schema from one database to other database(database created at runtime)

```
string sql = "create database " + str1;

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
connection.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
Response.Write("database created");
connection.Close();
```

```
string sqll = "(select * into " + str1 + ".cost_category.cost_category_info 
              from ERPAccounting.cost_category.cost_category_info where 1=2)
              (select * into " + str1 + ".dbo.cost_centre_info from 
              ERPAccounting.cost_centre.cost_centre_info where 1=2)"

connection.Open();
SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(sqll, connection);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ad.Fill(ds);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using C#, object DDL can be obtained by using `SMO` objects and then executed in the database where the objects need to be copied to.  In the example below, references to `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo,` `Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo`, `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc`, and `System.Data.SqlClient` are necessary.  The DDL is first obtained from the SMO objects, then it used as the `CommandText` for the `SqlCommand` that is executed in the destination database.  This example is for tables, but other objects (views, stored procedures, etc.) can also be copied using this method.

```
            //set initial catalog to destination database
            string connStr = @"Data Source=YourServer;Initial Catalog=DestinationDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;";

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
            {
                //set source server and database using SMO objects
                Server srv = new Server(@"YourServer");
                srv.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = true;
                srv.ConnectionContext.StatementTimeout = 600;
                Database db = srv.Databases["SourceDatabase"];

                //configure Scripter for DDL
                Scripter script = new Scripter(srv);
                ScriptingOptions scriptOpt = new ScriptingOptions();

                //SQL command to execute DDL in destination database
                SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand();
                sql.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();

                //this can changed to views, SPs, etc. as needed
                foreach (Table t in db.Tables)
                {
                    //check for system objects
                    if (!t.IsSystemObject)
                    {
                        StringCollection sc = t.Script(scriptOpt);
                        foreach (string s in sc)
                        {
                            //assign and execute DDL
                            sql.CommandText = s;
                            sql.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Excellent, this works perfectly, thank you. The line "Scripter script = new Scripter(srv);" does not seem to be used here - and calling its Script (t) seems to generate the same output as the t.Script(scriptOpt) call. Good to have both options.